# gst-launch-1.0 does not record audio only video

Tags: gstreamer, transcoding, gst-launch-1.0

Hi guys with the help of rtranscode i managed this pipe to work. But it only records video it does not include sound. What am I missing ?

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="http://example/2.ts" is-live=true keep-alive=true do-timestamp=true retries=10 typefind=true blocksize=16384 \
!  tsdemux parse-private-sections=false program-number=-1 name=demux demux.audio_0101 \
!  queue \
!  aacparse \
!  avdec_aac \
!  audioconvert dithering=0 \
!  audio/x-raw,channels=2 \
!  voaacenc bitrate=65536 \
!  matroskamux name=stream streamable=true demux. \
!  queue \
!  h264parse \
!  video/x-h264,alignment=au \
!  omxh264dec \
!  video/x-raw,width=910,height=512 \
!  omxh264enc target-bitrate=294912 control-rate=variable \
!  h264parse \
!  filesink location="test.h264"
```

Comment: The audio path does not even have a file sink. On top of that the video file format does not support an audio track. The whole pipeline looks like you are not sure what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch well I am a total beginner on gst, can you pls. help so this all will make sense? Thanks in advance!